# Windows Server 2003 GPO Applied to only a few users?

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, group-policy

How do I apply the policy:

Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Terminal Services/Client Server data redirection/Do not allow client printer redirection only to a few users?

Do I have to create 2 OU's and 2 policies just for this? I see I can't create a group and apply the GPO to the group and add the users to that group.

How do I selectively apply a policy to only a few users without creating a whole new OU for them (and without changing each user's AD properties individually)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be problematic. The setting you're trying to configure is a computer setting and is applied to the computer and therefore will affect everyone logging on to that computer regardless of any security filtering that you do. There isn't a corresponding user configuration setting for this so you're going to have to set this on a user by user basis in ADUC. You can use a tool such as ADModify.NET to make the change in bulk and then selectively enable drive redirection for only those users which you choose to have redirected drives in their TS session.

Comment: +1 - Right on. This is a scenario when no helpful combination of loopback group policy processing, filtering by security group, or any other hackery is going to work. The poster is going to *have* to modify the setting on individual user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Group Policy Security Filtering](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Group-Policy-Security-Filtering.html). It's basically the same as the per-group GPO you're imagining, only implimentation is a bit... unintuitive.

You may have some problems trying to do it on computer configuration elements though, rather than user elements. You may be able to find an equivalent setting in the user section of Group Policy editor.

Comment: -1 - That's not going to work for a computer setting being filtered by user. Even using loopback group policy processing won't do what the poster wants.